# Updating the size of a ScrolledPanel without scrolling to the top

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Consider the following dummy application:

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel


class MyPanel(ScrolledPanel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ScrolledPanel.__init__(self, parent, size=(128, 64))

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False, scroll_y=True)

    def add_text_line(self, text):
        self.sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label=text))
        self.sizer.Layout()
        self.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=False, scroll_y=True)


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title='Test Window')

        self.line_number = 1

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        button = wx.Button(self, label='Add a row')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_row, button)
        sizer.Add(button)

        self.panel = MyPanel(self)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def add_row(self, _):
        self.panel.add_text_line('Line number ' + str(self.line_number))
        self.line_number += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    MainWindow(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

It contains a `ScrolledPanel` to which content is dynamically added when the user presses the button. The `ScrolledPanel` seems to update its size and layout okay, but if I scroll partway down the list and press the button, the `SetupScrolling` call causes the scroll position to jump back to the top. This will be unacceptable behavior for my application. How can I do one of the following?

1. Lay out the scrolled area without jumping to the top
2. Call `SetupScrolling` only if the content area has actually changed size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5914064/371228) on a similar question, I found that I needed to call `FitInside` instead of `SetupScrolling` to get the scroll bars to update. This does not affect the scroll position.

My example code needs to be modified to change `MyPanel.add_text_line` to this:

```
    def add_text_line(self, text):
        self.sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label=text))
        self.sizer.Layout()
        self.FitInside()
```